# How to insert json data into MariaDB using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, mariasql

I'm inserting JSON data into MariaDB using NodeJs. Getting below error  while inserting data. Please advise what cause to get error. Actually Column data1 no empty or null values.Why am i getting below error ?

```
{ [Error: Column 'data1' cannot be null] code: 1048 }
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `from_excel` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `data2` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Code which i'm using to insert data.

```
var Client = require('mariasql');
var c = new Client({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'xxxx',
  password : 'xxxx',
  db : 'Metrics'
});




const workbook = xlsx.readFile(__dirname + '/test.xlsx');
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
var json=xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
console.log(json.length);
      for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
    {
        var post  = {data1: json[i].data1, data2: json[i].data2};

        var sql = c.query('INSERT INTO elements_from_excel (data1,data2) VALUES (?,?)', post, function(err, result) {
            console.log(sql);
        if(err){console.log(err);}
            else {console.log("success");}

     });

    }
    c.end();
```

Comment: Do you want the JSON inserted as a string? Or are `data1` and `data2` columns that you want the values inserted into?

Comment: yes, want to insert json to two columns of the table. first column name data1 and second column name data2.

Answer (score 1):

What could be happening is that the resulting insert statement being run is as follows:

```
INSERT into from_excel (data1, data2) VALUES (`data1` = \'data1value\', `data2` = \'value\', ?)
```

Try replacing the query string with the following instead:

```
var post  = {data1: json[i].data1, data2: json[i].data2};

var sql = c.query('INSERT INTO from_excel SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
            console.log(sql);
        if(err){console.log(err);}
            else {console.log("success");}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `INSERT INTO from_excel VALUES (?)`, although it's quite possible that you'll encounter other errors when you fix this one.

Comment: Thank you. Good catch! Now i'm getting { [Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1] code: 1136 }

Comment: That's because you are inserting one value, but apparently have more than one column in the table. Then it should be `INSERT INTO from_excel (column_name) VALUES (?)`. Or, if it's two columns, then `INSERT INTO from _excel (data1, data2) VALUES (?, ?)` and bind accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Now inserting NULL values only. So i made not null in the table structure and its giving an error data1 cannot be null] code: 1048.But no null value in data1 column. Please advise.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how your `json` is initialized, so it's hard to say anything. Are you sure they aren't `NULL`s? For starters, paste your updated code, and also add debug printing before running the query, with the values that you bind to the query. In the initial error we could see that the server was receiving explicit `NULL` in the query, it's not a default that it uses, so the problem must be in the code.

Comment: I have updated the code. I am reading the value from excel file and converting into json and inserting into DB.Actually i can insert directly without converting json. But i have one scenario to do same.I have only one row in the excel, though i'm getting same error.

Comment: Okay, so, `sheet_to_json` returns an array of JSON objects, and `json[i]` is a JSON object, is it right? But then, aren't you supposed to parse it with `JSON.parse` or something, before referring to the elements `data1` and `data2`? I think it used to be so, maybe things have changed.

Comment: There is no such thing as JSON object. You should say Js Object or Object or JSON string

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the function you are calling receive the exact type of data they expect.